# How to pass flutter riverpod ref.read() function to another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, riverpod

**Here is my Custom reusable Widget code.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class MyFloatingActionButton extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Function(ProviderRef ref) onPressed;

  MyFloatingActionButton(this.onPressed);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => onPressed,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here is the the parent widget :**

```
floatingActionButton: MyFloatingActionButton((ref) => ref.read(myProvider)._increase())
```

**Here is myProvider**

```
class CountNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int num = 0;
  void _increase() {
    num ++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
final myProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) {
  return CountNotifier();
});
```

After passinging the Function to its child its not working anymore. But in the parent widget it just working fine.

I am expecting to pass ref.read() function to any child widget.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function won't be called as your code:

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () => onPressed,
  tooltip: 'Increment',
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
);
```

Because `() => onPressed` means a function always returns a value, and the value is your callback function. **You have never called your callback function!**

So you should call it like this: `() => onPress(ref)`.

I don't know what you want to implement, but my suggestion is just only to use the `ref` from the parent widget, don't pass the `ref` by hand.

Comment: I tried it before. It's not taking ref as an argumnet. The argument type 'WidgetRef' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderRef'.

Comment: @Arman `ProviderRef` is used to organize the data of Provider outside of the Widget tree. But your code is in the Widget tree. You can try replacing `ProviderRef` with `WidgetRef`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```dart
// parent:
floatingActionButton: MyFloatingActionButton(ref.read(myProvider)._increase)
```

child:

```dart
class MyFloatingActionButton extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyFloatingActionButton(this.onPressed);

  final Function() onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }
}
```